# Using Web Fonts in Custom SharePoint MasterPage HTML

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have to use a web font that from another website and the URL of that is at the below.

```
<a href="http://fast.fonts.com/cssapi/b0549848-32a3-4c8e-a13e-810394960364.css">http://fast.fonts.com/cssapi/b0549848-32a3-4c8e-a13e-810394960364.css</a>
```

To add this web font I have used the following statement in my MasterPage's HTML file.

```
<link href="http://fast.fonts.com/cssapi/b0549848-32a3-4c8e-a13e-810394960364.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

My MasterPage is a custom one. I tried the following statement but it didnot work because when I tried to save the MasterPages's HTML file an error occurs saying the file should have the .aspx extension.

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="<%$SPrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/MyCustomTheme/mycss.css%>" runat="server" After="corev15.css"/>
```

The problem I think the custom web font will be replaced by the default font in the default CSS file in the SharePoint Site.

So what can I do for to obstruct this problem? Please could someone help me solve this?

Thanks and regards,

Chiranthaka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually SharePoint requires secure connections for external resources. So the URLmust start with `https://` instead of `http://`.

I changed the URL from `

to

`<link href="https://fast.fonts.com/cssapi/b0549848-32a3-4c8e-a13e-810394960364.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Thanks guys however you have replied me ASAP.
Regards,
Chiranthaka

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `http://`

```
 <link href="fast.fonts.com/cssapi/b0549848-32a3-4c8e-a13e-810394960364.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```